# Discrete random variables; min and max

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given a random variable $X$ I have to find min and max of $Z$. Since I am just starting with this chapter of random variables it is unclear to me how to approach this problem.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'Find $Z$'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $Z$ is a random variable and you are trying to find its probability distribution.
$$\
Z=\min{\{X, 2\}}=\{0, 1, 2\} \\
P(Z=0)=P(X=0)=0.1 \\
P(Z=1)=P(X=1)= 0.2 \\
P(Z=2)=P(X\geq2)=P(X=2) + P(X=3) + P(X=5) = 0.7
$$
Try to solve (b)

Comment: $Z=max\{ X,2 \} =\{ 2,3,4 \} P(Z=2) = P(X<2) = P(X=0) +P(X=1)= 0.1+0.2, P(Z=3) = P(X=3)=0.2 ,  P(Z=4) = P(X=4)=0.2$       is it correct? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There is a small mistake. Probabilities are not summing up to 1 for $Z$. Try to find the missing term. **Hint:** It's in $P(Z=2)$

Comment: Should I include $P(X=2)$ that way probability adds up to 1?

Comment: Yes because $X=2 \implies Z=2$. Hence in your answer $P(Z=2)=P(X\leq 2)$